# Good Books for Solaris

Tags: unix, solaris

Can anyone suggest a good book for Learning Solaris 10.

I know the [Bill Calkins](http://unixed.com/books/books.htm) books but they are certification centric.

There is [Unix and Linux System Administration Handbook](http://www.admin.com/) as well which covers all flavors of Linux and Unix (Solaris,HP Unix and AIX).

Is there a good book which is entirely dedicated towards the 'practical' side of Solaris 10 Administration.

Comment: Questions regarding professional education are off topic per the [updated FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to find many books about the practical side of Solaris 10 administration for a few reasons:

- The [official documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18752_01/) from Sun/Oracle is a great resource by itself.
- The technology has changed quickly in the last few years and any book would soon be out of date.
- There are several newer books about OpenSolaris, but bear in mind that practical OpenSolaris administration can be significantly different from Solaris 10 administration.

I'll try and point you towards the Solaris 10 resources that I find most useful, assuming you have a basic knowledge of Unix concepts:

- The [Solaris Internals wiki](http://www.solarisinternals.com/) is an invaluable, up-to-date resource for practical administration of Zones, ZFS and DTrace.
- If you care about performance, look no further than [Brendan Gregg](http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/). He's written two books relating to performance including the recent DTrace bible.
- If you're installing multiple servers you need to know about the [Jumpstart Enterprise Toolkit](http://wikis.sun.com/display/JET/Home) (JET).
- [Live Upgrade](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19253-01/821-0438/index.html) is essential for safe patching and upgrades.
- For security, learn about the [Solaris Security Toolkit](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19056-01/sec.tk42/819-1402-10/index.html) (JASS).

Comment: I completely agree about existing official documentation, including Advanced Administration Guide, and the detailed guides for various operations and management. To learn more about CIFS and ZFS, there are outstanding guides again, part of the official documentation.  New DTrace book: http://www.amazon.com/DTrace-Dynamic-Tracing-Solaris-FreeBSD/dp/0132091518/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1306687416&sr=8-1 is definitely outstanding. I wish I had more time to spend with it. I will second the warning about OpenSolaris. Definitely, make sure that keep this in mind, as differences are not always obvious.

Comment: The ["Less known Solaris Features" tutorials](http://www.c0t0d0s0.org/pages/lksfbook.html) are also a good source to complement that list.

Comment: @pconcepcion: Wow, I've read Joerg's blog before but never noticed that. Good find!

Answer (score 0):

The OpenSolaris Bible is a great resource for Solaris 10 and OpenSolaris. Bonus, you get to know things that will come in Solaris 11.